# django on ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu

I have done everything said on the following page.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Django
```

but it gives me an error page.

> MOD_PYTHON ERROR
>
> ProcessId:      2220 Interpreter:
>   'localhost.localdomain'
>
> ServerName:
>   'localhost.localdomain' DocumentRoot: 
>   '/etc/apache2/htdocs'
>
> URI:            '/' Location:
>   '/' Directory:      None Filename:
>   '/etc/apache2/htdocs' PathInfo:
>   '/'
>
> Phase:          'PythonHandler'
>   Handler:
>   'django.core.handlers.modpython'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
>       default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1229, in _process_target
>       result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py",
>   line 1128, in _execute_target
>       result = object(arg)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/modpython.py",
>   line 228, in handler
>       return ModPythonHandler()(req)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/modpython.py",
>   line 191, in **call**
>       self.load_middleware()
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 33, in load_middleware
>       for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/functional.py",
>   line 276, in **getattr**
>       self._setup()
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 40, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 75, in **init**
>       raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on
>   sys.path? Does it have syntax
>   errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE,
>   e))
>
> ImportError: Could not import settings
>   'examples.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named examples.settings

what could be wrong?

complete noob here.

Comment: mod_python is dead. Consider moving to mod_wsgi at your earliest convenience.

Comment: that is phase II. at first, it would be easier for me, if somebody could tell me what i am doing wrong with this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deploying django project for production under ubuntu server it is recommended to use WSGI. Just fallow the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Installing apache with wsgi under ubuntu is easy:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

In case you just want to explore django you do not need to setup apache or anything. Just use `manage.py runserver` instead.